# Spring MVC: Is it possible to bind a specific HttpMessageConverter to a @RequestBody-annotated parameter?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application with the default `AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter`. The bound Jackson `ObjectMapper` instance has a custom `SimpleModule` registered so now it supports `Multimap` from the Google Guava library.

```java
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper()
            .setSerializationInclusion(NON_NULL)
            .configure(FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
            .registerModule(new SimpleModule()
                    .addSerializer(multimapType, multimapDuplicateKeysSerializer)
                    .addDeserializer(multimapType, multimapJsonDeserializer)
            );
}
```

And suppose I have the following method in my controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(method = POST)
@ResponseStatus(OK)
public Object post(
    @RequestBody final Multimap<String, Object> multimap
) {
    ...
}
```

At this step everything is fine. Now I have to validate the multimap for empty or blank keys, and return HTTP 400 if there any invalid keys found in the incoming multimap. This is a trivial operation and can be easily done traversing the incoming multimap and throwing an exception to be handled in the controller advice. But this has at least the next flaws:

- I don't want to validate multimaps directly somewhere in my controller or the associated service.
- If it's a flaw: I couldn't make it work with Spring MVC annotations like `@Valid`, `@ModelAttribute` etc, but now I don't really care for these, because of the following:
- I don't want the multimap to be validated after it's deserialized, because I would like to validate the incoming request body at the parser level somewhere in a specific `HttpMessageConverter` -- the validation I need is purely a JSON stream validation that would work perfectly even for big multimaps not requiring the whole multimap to be deserialized before the validation. If possible, of course.

Is it possible to bind a specific `HttpMessageConverter` to a specific `@RequestBody` only? Probably something like:

```java
@RequestMapping(method = POST)
@ResponseStatus(OK)
public Object post(
    @SomeMagicSpringAnnotationHere("specificHttpMessageConverter") @RequestBody final Multimap<String, Object> multimap
    OR
    @AnotherMagicSpringAnnotationHere("specificObjectMapper") @RequestBody final Multimap<String, Object> multimap
    OR
    @WhateverMagicSpringAnnotationHere @RequestBody final Multimap<String, Object> multimap
) {
    ...
}
```

Or am I wrong about this approach and it can be accomplished with something more Spring-related and more elegant? Any suggestions are very appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just implement your own custom `MultiMapHttpMessageConverter` just for this type and register it in your mvc configuration. (I even think registering it is a bean is enough as `HttpMessageConverter` instances are automatically detected and registered.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the reply. If I understand how it should work, then I probably will have two issues: 1) Such a `HttpMessageConverter` must override the existing `AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter` which must not support multimaps now; 2) It would be bound to a all multimaps in the whole application, not specific ones. Am I right, or am I missing something?

Comment: Why should it override the one, it will be used next to the other one. The conversion mechanism detects the type of the method argument and tries to find a suitable converter. It will indeed be for all `MultiMap` arguments you cannot have a single one for just a single method/controller. That isn't how the mechanism works.

Comment: Thinking about it you could create an annotation to use instead of `@RequestBody` and implement a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` which takes care of that. You can then put the other annotation on your argument instead of `@RequestBody`. You can then do anything you want inside that class.

Comment: @M.Deinum Hm, I was trying to experiment with `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` but couldn't make it work for some reason (maybe because the parameter was annotated with `@RequestBody` already). I'll take a look deeper.

Comment: you have to make another annotation to use instead of `@RequestBody` (see my answer I typed recently).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a specialized annoation i.e `@MultiMapRequestBody`

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface MultiMapRequestBody {

    boolean required() default true;
```

Then create a `MultiMapRequestBodyMethodArgumentResolver` which knows what to do.

```
public class MultiMapRequestBodyMethodArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    public  boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.hasParameterAnnotation(MultiMapRequestBody.class); // maybe check argument type too.
    }

    public  Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
        NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        // Logic for validation and converting using Jackson
        // Take a look at MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter

    }
}
```

Now you can handle the body conversion and validation yourself. You might want to take a look at the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` for some inspiration on how to read and parse the body. Or maybe extend one of the `abstract` classes used for argument conversion.

Now in your request handling method use the `@MultiMapRequestBody` instead of the `@RequestBody` annotation.

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST)
@ResponseStatus(OK)
public Object post(
    @MultiMapRequestBody final Multimap<String, Object> multimap
) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll take a look.

Comment: Well, now it looks trivial and as simple as I wanted it to be... Exactly what I need. I swear, I was I trying to apply it as well. Whatever I did with it, I did it wrong for any reason. No need to overtime anyway and I need some vacation. Thank you **very** much!